# How to bound a campus map in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new in this programming language so I kinda copy and paste the codes found in the net and then I've found and tried using these codes in bounding a certain area and it works:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
// Create a LatLngBounds that includes the city of Adelaide in Australia.
private LatLngBounds ADELAIDE = new LatLngBounds(
new LatLng(-35.0, 138.58), new LatLng(-34.9, 138.61));
// Constrain the camera target to the Adelaide bounds.
mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(ADELAIDE);
```

But when I changed it using my campus coordinates into like this:

```
private LatLngBounds CPUBounds = new LatLngBounds(
new LatLng(10.732581, 122.548413), new LatLng(10.730052, 122.549958));
```

My app suddenly stop working. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste the Logcat to review the Error

From If you want to show the specific position try the following code

To Move Camera Position Over a Specific Region Use this ,

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 
                           zoomWidth, 
                           zoomHeight, 
                           zoomPadding));

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(10.732581, 122.548413), 
                           zoomHeight));
```

If u want to add a marker Over region use

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                       .position(new LatLng(10.732581, 122.548413))
                       .title("campus name"));
```

To Disable the Dragging Use
`mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);`

but it doesn't disable map zoom by touch on map. for that use Following Code
`googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);`

Comment: What if I just want to restrict the view in my campus only? Like the I cant swipe it past the campus. How do I do it?